# Trying to make nested json and point to the same object using multiple keys

Tags: json

let say i have this JSON data

```
"value1" : { "name" : "Foo" }
"value2" : { "name" : "14" }
"value3" : { "gender" : "Male" }
```

now i am trying to do this

```
"value1', "value2", "value3" : { "name" : "Foo" }
```

or maybe this if at all possible

```
["value1', "value2", "value3"] : { "name" : "Foo" }
```

so in a nutshell i have data that i would like to access using multiple pointers point to the same data in a JSON formate so that i don't have to repeat the same data for different pointers

here is an example of data:

```
 "Model 1" : { "E-Series" : ["Green", "Purple"] }
```

let say "Model 2" has same info as "Model 1"  how can point "Model 2" to "Model 1" data object in JSON without repeating the same code over and over again

Comment: This is beyond JSON syntax capabilities. You can probably make use of JSON-LD or HAL JSON (http://stateless.co/hal_specification.html) for interlinking. Or devise your own. (And it will not necessarily be shorter notation, if that is what you are seeking, but will help with references.)

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible in JSON format. You can simulate it in code for example for Model2 set `"ref": "Model1"` and then programmatically read data from object Model1.

JSON hasn't got this feature by design.

Answer (score 0):

This is not correct JSON syntax, and JSON does not have provisions for links. Your options are for encoding object references are:

- LD+JSON (http://json-ld.org/)
- HAL+JSON (http://stateless.co/hal_specification.html)
- JSON-R (http://java.dzone.com/articles/json-r-json-extension-deals)
- dojox.json.ref (https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojox/json/ref.html)
- etc, etc, ...
- your custom data model for references

The benefit of using something more or less standard is a better (future) integration, but it may not be relevant for your task.